# How are contextuality and locality related?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality, non-locality

I know how quantum non-locality is defined in Wikipedia

> quantum nonlocality is a characteristic of some measurements made at a microscopic level that contradict the assumptions of local realism found in classical mechanics. Despite consideration of hidden variables as a possible resolution of this contradiction, some aspects of entangled quantum states have been demonstrated irreproducible by any local hidden variable theory

[[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_nonlocality)] and how quantum contextuality is defined in Wikipedia

> Quantum contextuality is a foundational concept in quantum mechanics stating that the outcome one observes in a measurement is dependent upon what other measurements one is trying to make. More formally, the measurement result of a quantum observable is dependent upon which other commuting observables are within the same measurement set.

[[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_contextuality)]

I however can't grasp how they are related or even if they are related at all. Can anyone help me with a high level explanation?

Comment: Look at the section: Locality versus non-contextual hidden variables
http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bell%27s_theorem